Create Windows custom event log
I need to create custom event logs like its done by OpenSSH (see screenshot).
I tried to add registry keys manually. Then I found the file:
https://github.com/PowerShell/openssh-portable/blob/0dd6d2cd219a0eb75dc3a498ee5a23973239ca6d/contrib/win32/openssh/Openssh-events.man
and tried to install it with minor modifications (provider name and GUID) using wevtutil like its done in OpenSSH installation script.
Modified file: https://gist.github.com/ievgiienko/c2d09a9429903b8665351e80a3054ca0
I've also restarted EventLog service and OS after the changes.
The problem is that in both cases the logs are not display as SomeTest folder children and slashes remain in their names.
Does anybody know how to fix this?


You're gonna have to show us the modified version and the exact wevtutil command you ran if you want help figuring out what went wrong :)

Sure: https://gist.github.com/ievgiienko/c2d09a9429903b8665351e80a3054ca0

You should put the relevant code in the question.
